# Filter a value from dropdown reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, drop-down-menu, filtering

I am having a multiple cards on my screen. Each card shows the string as **"Popular"**/ **"Latest"**/ "**Old**". I am getting these value on the card from the backend. I have to implement the filter option, which filter these cards on the basis of Popularity, oldest etc. I have done this till now, but not sure how to filter those cards.

```
<Dropdown
                          id="sorting"
                          items={this.sortOptions}
                          itemToString={(item) => (item ? item.label : "")}
                          onChange={this.onChange}
                          name="sorting"
                          label="All"
                          titleText="Sort"
                          type="default"
                        />
 sortOptions = [
    { value: "Popular", label: "Popular" },
    { value: "Old", label: "Old" },
    { value: "Latest", label: "Latest" },
  ];
```

OnChange Method:

```
onChange = (event) => {
    let filtered = this.sortOptions.filter(
      (val) => val.value === ProductState.Old
    );
    console.log("filtered", filtered);
  };
```

console ouput: `Object { value: "Old", label: "Old" }`
But i want to filter my cards, based on the value selected in the dropdown. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to filter the filter options themselves.  What are these "cards" you're referring to?

Comment: Inside the filter function, do the comparison with the event value.

Comment: @David Cards which contain these values as string. lets suppose I have 10 cards, with 3 cards as "Old", 4 cards as "Popular" and so on. So If I select "Popular" from dropdown, then I want only 4 cards to show up on screen

Comment: @Singh: And where in your component are these "cards"?  If you haven't implemented them yet then that would be your first step before trying to filter them.

Comment: I have already created those cards, but not wriiten that code in the above question

Comment: @Singh: Please update the question to include relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your onChange function to this:

```js
   onChange = (event) => {
    let filtered = this.cardArray.filter( // change cardArray according to your name
      (card) => card.tag === event.value // change tag according to your card code
    );
   setCardArray(filtered) // change setCardarray according to your setState function
  };
```

Basically you filter your cards state using the selected value of the dropwdown and update the card state with the filtered array.

Right now you are using the filter function on the wrong array.

Comment: What is setArrayCard? I did not get this: change setCardarray according to your setState function

Comment: It's the setState function for your cardArray if you are using hooks.
If you are using React.Components use changed that with this.setState({cardVariableHere: filtered})

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have a data locality problem at the moment.

First make sure, where the data that needs to be filtered comes from and where is it stored.

The onChange method only "reacts" on the user input. For example, if you open up the dropdown and select an option, the onChange method gets triggered. The "event" in your onChange method contains the option that you just clicked on.

onChange = (**event**) => {

};

log the event to the console and see how you can access the data within.

```
onChange = (event) => {

    console.log("dropDownOnChangeEvent", event);
  };
```

Now you have to use the selected "sortOption" to either make the correct call to the backend where you get your cards from, or if you already have all data in your browser apply the filter method on this data.

Comment: i am getting this in my console: Object { value: "Popular", label: "Popular" } but really not sure how it will filter my cards which contain "Popular", "Old", "Latest"

Comment: Cards which contain these values as string. lets suppose I have 10 cards, with 3 cards as "Old", 4 cards as "Popular" and so on. So If I select "Popular" from dropdown, then I want only 4 cards to show up on screen

Comment: how to apply the filter method, thats my question from the beginning :D